# PTAM is not generating executables

Tags: ros, ethzasl-ptam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running Ubuntu 14.04.2 with ROS Indigo. I have the catkinized version of ethzasl_ptam installed, and catkin_make runs with no errors. When I run `roslaunch ptam ptam.launch` I receive the following error message:
`ERROR: cannot launch node of type [ptam/ptam]: can't locate node [ptam] in package [ptam]`
When I search the ptam directory, I see that there are no executables. In the rosbuild version of ethzasl_ptam the executables could be found in the ptam/bin directory, but this does not exist either. Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210597/ptam-is-not-generating-executables/) by [aland_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/11466/aland_t/) on ROS Answers with karma: 107 on 2015-06-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

catkin does out-of-source builds, so all binaries end up in the `/path/to/workspace/devel/lib/pkg_name`, not in a `bin` subdir of the source pkg.

Have you sourced the `devel/setup.bash`? Where does `roscd ptam` take you?

Also: how is your workspace setup?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aland_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/11466/aland_t/) on 2015-06-04**:
Ahhh, roscd ptam takes me into the ptam directory. The binaries are right where you said they would be and, sourcing devel/setup.bash resulted in roslaunch working. Is there some command I can add to .bashrc, so I don't have to source devel/setup.bash every time?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-06-04**:
Well you could add it to your `.bashrc`, see [Environment Setup](http://wiki.ros.org/jade/Installation/Ubuntu#jade.2BAC8-Installation.2BAC8-DebEnvironment.Environment_setup) in the Jade installation tutorial fi.